# Showing linear dependence in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-3\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $V_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\
9\\
-6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $V_3=\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-7\\
h\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

For what value of h is the span {v1,v2,v3} linear dependent.

This be my work.

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 5&  0 \\
-3&9& -7&   0 \\
2& -6 &   h&   0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

then doing 3r1+r3 and -2r1+r2

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 5&  0 \\
0&0& 8&   0 \\
0&0 &   h-10&   0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

for what values of $h$, is the determinant $\det{(v_1,v_2,v_3)}$ exactly $0$? What if it is always $0$ no matter what the value of $h$ is?

Comment: Hmm I guess h can be any number. Because you have no free variables?

Comment: You know that if $v_i$ are linearly independent, then $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 = 0$ (where $\alpha_i$ are scalars) implies $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = 0$. This is equivalent to discussing the determinant of the matrix formed by the three vectors in column (or row) form.

Comment: Furthermore, the second column of your matrix $A$ is wrong. You have flipped the 2nd and 3rd values of $v_2$ and changed a sign. Hope you can see it clearer now! Cheers.

Comment: I see b.c linear independent has the solution ax=0 then x is zero. But then I guess if it linear dependent then h can be any value because you have free variable.

Comment: What do you mean by *free variable*?

Comment: I mean for example if you have a for example a 3x4 matrix then the column in which there is no pivot is the free variable.

Comment: Well, what you are trying to analyze is the character of the system $A \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{0}$, whose *extended matrix* is $(A|\mathbf{0})$ which is a $3\times 4$ matrix. Have a look to Rouché's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Adding the last zero column is irrelevant; with Gaussian elimination, you can not only decide if a set of vectors is linearly independent, but also tell what vectors are linear combinations of the remaining ones.

Your elimination is good, the reduced matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 5\\
0&0& 8\\
0&0 &   h-10
\end{bmatrix}
and this shows the three vectors are linearly dependent for all values of $h$.

The elimination shows, in particular, that the second vector is equal to the first one multiplied by $-3$ (linear relations among columns holding in the reduced matrix hold the same in the original matrix).

Since the last column is not a multiple of the first one, a basis of the subspace generated by $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ is $\{v_1,v_3\}$.

Comment: I think I see since $x_3$ has a pivot being 8 it does not matter what h-10 is.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Exactly so.

Answer (score 0):

You must have zeros in last row, so $h+30=0$ and $h=-30$.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to look at $\det A$ where $A$ is the matrix formed by $v_1,v_2,v_3.$ As long as determinant is non zero the matrix is invertible so these three vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$.